# Javascript timeout after conditions is met

Tags: javascript

I have a condition that once met I want to timeout that function so it is not called again for X amount of time. After that time period it can be called once again if the condition is met. how can I achieve this?

```
    setTimeout(function captureTimeout() {
        console.log("CheckingScore");
        if (ctrack.getScore() >= 0.8){
        console.log("Capturing Data") ;

        setTimeout(captureTimeout(), 30000);

    }
}, 1000);

captureTimeout();
```

Fairly certain the above code it extremely wrong!

@JLRishe

I am getting the score of ctrack.getScore() which ranges from 0.0 - 1.0, If the value reaches 0.8 or above I want to execute a function which will capture elements of the page at that moment (Looking for a solution for this) but for now I just want to either give an Alert or Log the console with a message. Once executed I want a "cooldown" period of 30 seconds before that function can be executed again, so even if ctrack.getScore() reaches 0.8 or more I only want the function to execute after the cooldown has finished and if the condition is met again after that cooldown period. Hopefully that explains it a bit more?

Comment: You might want to look into `setInterval()` instead.

Comment: Can you describe your requirement a bit more concretely? It's not very clear from your example.

Comment: @NickDugger recursive setTimeouts are generally preferred over setIntervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure what you're trying to accomplish has nothing to do with `setTimeout`.

Basically what you need to do here is keep track of when the cooldown period is going to be over and either:

- Use an `if` statement to skip the code that calls your function until the cooldown period is over OR
- Put logic in the function to prevent it from doing anything until the cooldown period is over

I like the second option a bit better because it applies no matter who tries to call the function, and here's how you could do this:

```
var coolDownSeconds = 30,
    nextAllowedCapture = new Date();

function capturePage() {
    var now = new Date();

    if (nextAllowedCapture <= now) {
        // Do capture logic
        console.log("Capturing...");

        nextAllowedCapture = new Date();
        nextAllowedCapture.setSeconds(nextAllowedCapture.getSeconds() + 
                                      coolDownSeconds);
    } else {
        console.log("Can't capture again yet. This function can be executed again in " + 
                    (nextAllowedCapture.getTime() - now.getTime()) / 1000 +
                    " seconds.");
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3U7Ud/2/

Comment: can you implement the same sort of thing as is in my question so I can see how it functions?

Comment: Can you show us the contents of your `getScore()` method? I have provided a jsfiddle so you can see how the above functions, but I don't know how to further make it match your description without implementing a bunch of game logic.

Comment: If you could make a random number generated possibly? or series of buttons with different values 0-1 and then show how the code generates a response the first time but if the number is met again within the cooldown it doesnt execute a response, or it shows how long is left of the cooldown?

Comment: Ok, please see my updated fiddle. You need to watch the console to see the messages that it outputs.

Comment: Jsfiddle seems to be timing out on my browser at the moment, I will try it in a short while and get back to you!

Comment: It seems like your fiddle is exaclty what im looking for

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to keep a boolean flag to know if you should perform the logic in your function or not. If your function should perform the logic, then you can set the flag to false and start the timeout for when it will become true again. That way, additional calls to the function won't perform the logic until the timeout has finished. Something like this:

```
var flag = true;

function myFunction() {
    if (flag === true) {

        // Don't let this run again for 30s
        flag = false;
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            flag = true;
        }, 30000);

        // perform the rest of your function logic...
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you implement this with a similar thing to my question, e.g. a number 0 to 1 just so I can see how it works as I am not sure whether your answer or JLRishe's is the one I am looking for.

Comment: @DanW Both of our answers are two ways of accomplishing the same thing. Beyond that, it's simply a matter of preference.